# How to replace part of a string in Java, where it matches 1st few characters, escape some in between and matches some character at the end?

Tags: java, regex, datetime, timestamp, pattern-matching

I'm working on a Java which does some changes to an SQL file and covert it to an Oracle competible format.

It seems for changing the Timestamp\date values, I need to use an oracle function "To_TIMESTAMP" to change it to some oracle understandable formart.

Now to the real question. Below I have a String line;

> `(1,'Ctx_Log-Log','','08.03.2017','2017-03-08 10:59:31','10:59:32','2017-03-08 10:59:41')`

where I'm interested in only values like `'2017-03-08 10:59:31'` and `'2017-03-08 10:59:41'` and these value can occur more than 2 times. I want to change\replace them to 
`To_TIMESTAMP('2017-03-08 10:59:31','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` and `To_TIMESTAMP('2017-03-08 10:59:41','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

and I don't want to disturb the other values. I tried to regex solution, but I could only match and replace the start of the string, like

```
string.replaceAll(",'201", ",To_TIMESTAMP('201")
```

which replace it to `To_TIMESTAMP('2017-03-08 10:59:31'`
but I don't know how to replace the end part of `'2017-03-08 10:59:31'` to `'2017-03-08 10:59:31','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`
Any help will be appreciate. It doesn't matter which way or method is performed, as far as gives me the right solution. Thanks

Comment: Java or JavaScript? http://javascriptisnotjava.io

Comment: That was a typo, which should be quite obvious, as the title clearly describes Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do the trick is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String text = "(1,'Ctx_Log-Log','','08.03.2017','2017-03-08 10:59:31','10:59:32','2017-03-08 10:59:41')";
   String regex = "'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}'";
   String template = "TO_TIMESTAMP(%s,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')";

   Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);

   while (matcher.find()) {
       String value = matcher.group();
       text = text.replace(value, String.format(template, value));
   }

   System.out.println(text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a magic! I have worked with pattern matching before, but didn't know I can target the desired String\Value so easily.

Answer (score 1):

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

Why use mere text when you can use objects to communicate with your database?

### JDBC 4.2

As of JDBC 4.2, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database. No need to mess with passing strings, or using regex, or calling the Oracle [`TO_TIMESTAMP`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm) function.

### `LocalDateTime`

For your inputs such as `2017-03-08 10:59:31`, use `LocalDateTime`. This class represents a date and a time-of-day lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such, it is appropriate for database columns of a data type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

### ISO 8601

Your input strings nearly comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. Replace the SPACE character in the middle with a `T` to fully comply. The *java.time* class use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

### Example code

```
String input = "(1,'Ctx_Log-Log','','08.03.2017','2017-03-08 10:59:31','10:59:32','2017-03-08 10:59:41')";
String inputModified = input.substring( 1 , input.length()-1 ) ;  // Remove parens at front and back. In real work, I would check that they are indeed parens.
String[] parts = inputModified.split( "," );
for ( String part : parts ) {
    if( part.length()==21 ) { // Possibly a date-time value we are targeting.
        String s = part.replace( "'" , "" ); // Remove quote marks.
        s = s.replace( " " , "T" );  // To comply with ISO 8601 standard, replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.
        try {
            LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(s); // Convert string such as `2018-01-23T01:23:45` to a date-time object lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC.
            …
            myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
            …
        } catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
            // Unexpected input.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You might get better performance using a StringBuilder for the output, but here is the basic idea vis-a-vis the regular expression:

```
String input = "(1,'Ctx_Log-Log','','08.03.2017','2017-03-08 10:59:31','10:59:32','2017-03-08 10:59:41')";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("('[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}')" );
Matcher m = regex.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    input = input.replace(m.group(), String.format("TO_TIMESTAMP(%s,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')", m.group()));
}
System.out.printf("%s\n", input);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It's working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The idiom for replacing a pattern that may occur a variable number of times in a string is, taken from [the documentation of `Matcher.appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-), is:

```
    // '2017-03-08 10:59:31'
    Pattern dateTimePattern = Pattern.compile("'\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}'");
    Matcher dateTimeMatcher = dateTimePattern.matcher("(1,'Ctx_Log-Log','',"
            + "'08.03.2017','2017-03-08 10:59:31','10:59:32','2017-03-08 10:59:41')");
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    while (dateTimeMatcher.find()) {
        dateTimeMatcher.appendReplacement(result, "To_TIMESTAMP(" + dateTimeMatcher.group() + ')');
    }
    dateTimeMatcher.appendTail(result);
    System.out.println(result.toString());
```

The output from this snippet is:

> (1,'Ctx_Log-Log','','08.03.2017',To_TIMESTAMP('2017-03-08 10:59:31'),'10:59:32',To_TIMESTAMP('2017-03-08 10:59:41'))

If that were me I would want to add a further validation of the date-time string to make sure I don’t replace something that just looked like a date-time:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("''uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss''");
    Pattern dateTimePattern = Pattern.compile("'\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}'");
    // 2017-77-77 77:77:77 is not a valid date-time and should not be replaced.
    Matcher dateTimeMatcher = dateTimePattern.matcher("(1,'Ctx_Log-Log','',"
            + "'08.03.2017','2017-03-08 10:59:31','10:59:32','2017-77-77 77:77:77')");
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    while (dateTimeMatcher.find()) {
        String old = dateTimeMatcher.group();
        try {
            // For validation try to parse the string.
            LocalDateTime.parse(old, dtf);
            dateTimeMatcher.appendReplacement(result, "To_TIMESTAMP(" + old + ')');
        } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
            // Validation failed, this was not a date-time.
            System.err.println("Not replacing invalid date-time " + old);
            // To avoid changing anything replace the string with itself.
            dateTimeMatcher.appendReplacement(result, old);
        }
    }
    dateTimeMatcher.appendTail(result);
    System.out.println(result.toString());
```

> Not replacing invalid date-time '2017-77-77 77:77:77'
>
> (1,'Ctx_Log-Log','','08.03.2017',To_TIMESTAMP('2017-03-08
>   10:59:31'),'10:59:32','2017-77-77 77:77:77')

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner:

```
input = input.replaceAll("'\\d{4}(-\\d\\d){2} \\d\\d(:\\d\\d){2}'", "To_TIMESTAMP($0,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')");
```

FYI `$0` is a replacement back-reference for the *entire* match.

---

Some test code:

```
String input = "(1,'Ctx_Log-Log','','08.03.2017','2017-03-08 10:59:31','10:59:32','2017-03-08 10:59:41')";
input = input.replaceAll("'\\d{4}(-\\d\\d){2} \\d\\d(:\\d\\d){2}'", "To_TIMESTAMP($0, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')");
System.out.println(input);
```

Output:

```
(1,'Ctx_Log-Log','','08.03.2017',To_TIMESTAMP('2017-03-08 10:59:31', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'10:59:32',To_TIMESTAMP('2017-03-08 10:59:41', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
```